# Squawk code generation (4-digit octal identifier) in c++

Tags: c++, octal

I'm trying to generate in my C++ project squawk codes in order to assign them to a radar target.

Squawk codes are used to identified airplanes using secondary radar, they are 4 digit octal codes (eg 7066 7067 7070...) : [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transponder_(aeronautics)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transponder_%28aeronautics%29)

I would like to have a function that generate a squawk code based on the last one given, this code is at the moment stored into an int.

I would like to have something like this:

```
        while (IsSquawkInUse(LAST_ASSIGNED_MODEA_VFR) && LAST_ASSIGNED_MODEA_VFR < 7070) {
        if (LAST_ASSIGNED_MODEA_VFR >= 7067) {
            break;
        }
        else {
            //increment LAST_ASSIGNED_MODEA_VFR 
        }
    }
```

I still haven't found anything on how to actually do that without having to generate all the existing codes and pick the next one from thoses.

I'm still new to C++ and help would be greatly appreciated.

Cordialement

Comment: first of all `7067` is not an [octal constant](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/constants/) – `07067` is one. also how is a valid code generated? would a simple incriment be sufficent here?

Comment: Unclear what you need help with, but a) in C++ octal values are written with a leading zero, and b)usually only constants are written in all caps.

Comment: Can you store the code internally as a regular decimal number and only convert to octal when you need to display it? That way you could just use `++` to increment.

Comment: @Valerij A valid code is simply a 4 digit code that uses 7 as the last "number", that means all 4096 codes between 0000 and 7777.I don't need to store the code as an octal, i would rather keep it as an int. Quote from wikipedia _Squawk codes are four-digit octal numbers; the dials on a transponder read from zero to seven, inclusive. Thus the lowest possible squawk is 0000 and the highest is 7777. Four octal digits can represent up to 4096 different codes_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    // source number as string
    string x;
    cin >> x;
    // convert it into a number
    int y = 0;
    for (int i = 0, ilen = x.size(); i < ilen; ++i) {
        y *= 8; // it's octal
        y += x[i] - '0';
    }
    // add 1 to that number
    ++y;
    // if we have a code 7777, next should be 0000
    y = y & 07777;
    // clear string x, so that we can
    x.clear();
    // write an octal number there as string
    while (y) {
        x = char(y % 8 + '0') + x;
        y /= 8;
    }
    // output that number
    cout << x << endl;
}
```

[Live version.](http://ideone.com/IBCaOy)